# Excel 2017 Get & Transform, Select by math function?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Is there any way how to select data based on GPS coordinates in Excel 2016 by means of Get & Transform defined by mathematical function (e.g. curved rectangle)? See for example picture bellow with MH370 search area on 7th Arc. I am trying to select NOAA buoys which were traveling through search area. The source text file contains GPS position about each buoy four times a day, Buoy ID, Lattitude, Longitude, Date and Time.

[image: indicativearea_australianoverview]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

Comment: You need to implement some reference points of which you know the **exact** latitude and longitude. Then it is quite easy to calculate the latitude and longitude of any given pixel in between (taking into consideration the curvature of the earth).

Comment: I do not have a problem to calculate a new position based on two points. Unfortunately I can't download 37 millions of rows with buoy data into Excel table. I need to download/select data that are in curved rectangle only.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible if you're willing to write the filter math by hand, as there's no built-in functions to deal with geolocation data or calculate distances. If you include a sample of the input rows and the rules for which rows should be included, you'll have a better chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: to write a long answer a function you want to use as a filter is required. :) You can use few-step filtration as well, i.e. first fiter only coordinates starting with 67.*, 51.*, and then apply a function to them, this would probably decrease processing time.